# What do I need to run AppiumDesktop for an iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, appium-desktop

I am running an app from an `npm run ios` command in a project that my developers gave me using the WebStorm IDE, which opens an iOS simulator. I also have the most recent ipa file in my downloads. My developers are only available about 2am - 6am my time so it is difficult to get answers.

I want to be able to gather elements from an inspector and the simulator opens an iPhone 11 by default. I'm on macOS Catalina 10.15.2. I am guessing on `platformName` and `versionName` based on other answers. I do not have a test framework with capabilities defined to look at.

I have guessed on these desired capabilities:

```
{
  "allowTestPackages": "true",
  "app": "/Users/<me>/Downloads<ipa file>",
  "appPackage": "<package name>",
  "platformName": "iOS",
  "noReset": "true",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 11",
  "automationName": "XCUITest",
  "platformVersion": "13.3"
}
```

The result of hitting start session is:

> Misconfigured -- Unsupported OS/browser/version/device combo: OS: 'unspecified', Browser: 'iphone', Version: '13.3.', Device: 'iPhone 11'

Do I need an UUID? And how would I find that? Do I need a `bundleID` as well? All the videos I can find on this subject are targeted to developers and assume some of this information is known.

Answer (score 1):

in Terminal, `xcrun simctl list -v` will show you all the simulator types your installed Xcode has available as well as a list of all the deviceId for all your real and simulated devices.

Behind the scenes, I'm guessing appium is running xcodebuild test-without-building using the -destination flag, which is filled out with something like this:

`-destination "platform=iOS Simulator,id=1FE7AAAA-A6AD-429C-A368-33E79F81598E,OS=12.4'"`

this Appium documentation [link](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) says there is a key called `udid` which you can specify to aim your test at a specific simulator you find in the `xcrun simctl list` command.

Answer (score 0):

got this running using the following instructions:

1.Remove webDriverAgent and let it reinstall before running the test
2.Use : capabilities.setCapability(“noReset”, true);
3.Make sure you are giving correct bundleId of the app already installed.

noReset had to be a boolean and not text